# Extract words from a string (words are separated with spaces and tabs, possibly multiple)

Tags: c, string, file-io

I'm trying to create a program in C that read inputs from a file, let it be `Input.inp` that contains strings with words that are separated with spaces and tabs, possibly multiple and then write to a file `Output.out`, with each word on a line. For example, the input file contains

```
Hi  my name         is Yang
```

then the output file will look like this

```
Hi
my
name 
is 
Yang
```

Also, the program will stop reading if it reach an end-of-file or reach a "#".

Below is my code. I get the character from the file, then check if it is a "#" or an end-of-file or not. If it is not then it will check if the character is a space, tab or end of line. If it is not then the character will be put to a string "word". Now, if we reach a space, tab or end of line then I'll print the string "word", set `pos` back to 0 and continue to do that. But this doesn't work. Can someone explain why my code fails and provide me a direction on how to do this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define maxn 300

int main(){
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    fin = fopen("splitwords.inp", "r");
    fout = fopen("splitwords.txt", "w");
    char buffer[maxn], word[maxn], ch, d;
    int i, pos = 0;

    while((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF && ch != '#'){
        while(ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\0'){
            word[pos] = ch;
            pos++;
            if((d = fgetc(fin)) == ' ' || d == '\t' || d == '\0'){
                word[pos] = '\0';
                fputs(word, fout);
                printf("%s", word);
                pos = 0;
            }
        }
        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0') continue;
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: Use `strtok` and the task will be much simpler

Comment: Inside your while loop, you use `d` to store the read character, but the condition tests `ch`, which never changes.

Comment: `ch` should be an `int`

Comment: _buffer_ is unused in your program, you do not need to compare the read character with the null character, it is not present in a valid text file

Comment: Why don't you use `scanf()` and the `"%s"` format?  It handles the space skipping automatically.  All you have to do is look for the `#`.  What should happen if the input is `abcd#efgh` — does that hash count as terminating the input?

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks about your proposal

As it is said in a remark, when you read a character use an *int* to save it rather than a *char*, you probably had a warning from your compiler to signal that problem on `while((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF` like *comparison is always true due to limited range of data type*, this is because *EOF* cannot be saved in a *char*. So in your code *ch* and *d* must be an *int*

Check the result of *fopen* to be sure you open your files.

It is better to add ( ) to avoid possible problem of priority between operators, so replace

> ```
> while((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF && ch != '#')
>
> while(ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\0'){
>
> if((d = fgetc(fin)) == ' ' || d == '\t' || d == '\0'){
>
> if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0')
> ```

by (without considering other possible problems)

```
while(((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) && (ch != '#'))

while((ch != ' ') && (ch != '\t') && (ch != '\0')){

if(((d = fgetc(fin)) == ' ') || (d == '\t') || (d == '\0')){

if((ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t') || (ch == '\0'))
```

As it is said in a remark if you enter in these two whiles :

> ```
> while((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF && ch != '#'){
>    while(ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\0'){
> ```

you will never be able to go out because *ch* is unchanged inside, so you write more and more in *word* and finally out of it with an undefined behavior (typically a crash).

You do not need to check the case of the null character, it is not present in a text file.

You missed to manage the case of a newline ('\n' and '\r')

Independently of the problem because *ch* unchanged you never check the read word is not enough too long to be placed in *word*, you cannot suppose it will in any cases.

In

> ```
> if((d = fgetc(fin)) == ' ' || d == '\t' || d == '\0'){
> ```

you missed to manage the case of a newline, and you do not have to manage the case of the null character.

The line

> ```
> if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0') continue;
> ```

is useless, it is at the end of the while-block so even without it you reloop

---

> create a program in C that read inputs from a file, let it be Input.inp that contains strings with words that is separated with spaces and tabs, possibly multiple and then write to a file Output.out, with each word on a line.

Your program is also too complicated, you do not need to save the word in memory (this has also the advantage to be able to manage words longer than 299), your goal is to put each word on separated lines in the output file, so a simple solution is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fin, *fout;
  
  if ((fin = fopen("splitwords.inp", "r")) == NULL)
    puts("cannot open splitwords.inp");
  else {
    if ((fout = fopen("splitwords.txt", "w"))  == NULL)
      puts("cannot open splitwords.txt");
    else {
      int word = 0; /* not inside a word */
      int c; /* an int to manage EOF */
      
      while (((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) && (c != '#')) {
        if ((c == ' ') || (c == '\t') ||
            (c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) { /* can use isspace() */
          if (word) {
            /* the space finishes a word, add the new line */
            fputc('\n', fout);
            word = 0; /* not in a word now */
          }
        }
        else {
          fputc(c, fout); /* char of word are placed in output file */
          word = 1; /* we are in a word */
        }
      }
      
      if (word) {
        /* we was reading a word, need to add the final newline */
        fputc('\n', fout);
      }
      
      fclose(fout);
    }
    
    fclose(fin);
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra f.c
/tmp % cat splitwords.inp
Hi  my name         is Yang
/tmp % ./a.out
/tmp % cat splitwords.txt 
Hi
my
name
is
Yang
```

Some explications and remarks :

- after you open a file I check the result to be sure the *fopen* success
- when I read a char I do not save it in a *char* but an *int*, to manage the case of EOF
- in the code above I compare to space and tab etc to allow you to see what I do easily but there is a lib function doing that perfectly : *isspace* look at it and other useful functions (*isalpha isdigit* ...). You can change the corresponding line to add any other characters as separator like '-' or punctuation (',' ';') etc

The code above just writes the non space/tab/newline in the output file, and more of that it just need to detect the end of a word to add a newline, this is the goal of my variable *word* valuing 1 when the previously managed character was not a space/tab/newline else 0

Answer (score -1):

Well there was a lot of errors i chnged to this and add my comments:

```
    while(ch != EOF && ch != '#') {
            word[pos] = ch;
            pos++;
            if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0') {
                word[pos] = '\0';
                fputs(word, fout);
                printf("%s\n", word);
                memset(word, '\0', maxn); //flush word
                pos = 0;

                while (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0') { // handle multiple whitespaces
                    ch = fgetc(fin);
                }
            } else {
                ch = fgetc(fin);
            }
    }
```

That works but:
1. Check `pos < maxn` because possible is memory fail.
2. Create function `bool isWhitespace(char c);` because multiple use condition with or is ugly.
3. Check file is open correcly `fin != NULL && fout != NULL`